# Why is it that the interval of convergence is half open?

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

I am given the following power series and asked to find the radius of convergence and determine the exact interval of convergence
$$\sum\biggr(\frac{3^n}{n\cdot 4^{n}}\bigg)x^n \Leftrightarrow \sum\bigg(\frac{3}{n^{1/n}\cdot 4}\bigg)^{n}x^n$$
If $a_n=(\frac{3}{n^{1/n}\cdot 4})^{n}$, then $\lim\sup|a_n|^{1/n}=\frac{3}{4}$, hence, the radius of convergence is $R=\frac{4}{3}$.

I'm then given that the interval of convergence is $I=[-\frac{4}{3},\frac{4}{3})$.

I am confused how exactly the author determined that the I.O.C. is half open, and how I can determine if the I.O.C. will be open, closed or half open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, convergence of a power series is only guaranteed inside the open interval $(-R,R)$, or inside the open disc $|z| < R$ in $\mathbb{C}$. If you want to check what happens on the boundary, you'll have to check each case independently.

In your case, when $x=4/3$, the series is simply the harmonic series which does not converge. When $x = -4/3$, you have the alternating harmonic series which does converge.

Comment: Ah, I see now. Since $f(x)=\sum a_n x^n$, we must check the boundaries of $I=(-R,R)$, i.e. check $x=-R$ and $x=R$ to see the behavior of the series on the I.O.C.

Answer (score 0):

Series convergence tests, e.g., Hadamard's formula for checking *radius of convergence*, are often inconclusive along the boundary; you must check the boundary separately, by plugging in boundary values, thus obtaining a new series (with no x's involved anymore) and again using some series convergence test, to check for convergence.